# Работа оператора switch в PHP

Tags: php, switch, тернарный-оператор

Изучаю PHP, добрался до оператора switch, пересмотрел множество примеров, но так и не понял как можно с помощью этого оператора реализовать подобное:

```
<?php
$speed = 90;
$limit = 80;

if ($speed > $limit) {
echo "Превышаем";
}

elseif ($speed < $limit) {
echo "Скорость в норме";
}

elseif ($speed == $limit) {
echo "Ты на грани";
}
else echo "Введи нормальную скорость";
?>
```

Вопрос в нагрузку, как (и возможно ли) подобное реализовать с помощью тернарного оператора?
Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: в тернарный оператор данную конструкцию конкретно в PHP лучше не переписывать или делать это очень осторожно. ибо там порядок кривоват

Comment: осталось понять, зачем с помощью этого оператора реализовывать подобное.

Comment: @teran а почему нет?

Comment: @teran  В PHP это может оказаться небольшой проблемкой, но вот в C# очень удобно некоторым

Comment: @АлексейШиманский достаточно просто сравнить количество кода.

Comment: @Ипатьев да ладно вам. если не говорить про отрефакторенный код, как у вас в ответе, то как минимум при тернарнике скушаются все `echo` все `if` и `elseif`. как раз все сократится)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так тернарник тут вообще не причем, он в любом случае здесь неуместен. Я говорил про свитч и набор if-ов. Последний будет проще

Comment: @Ипатьев ну switch в принципе массивен при любой логике. Так что в таком случае получается надо выбросить switch вообще и никогда не использовать)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну я вот тоже об этом подумал, но потом спохватился - если вариантов ваыбора много и по каждому нужно больше одного действия, то он будет уже удобнее ифов

Answer (score 7):

```
switch(true){
    case $speed > $limit:
        echo "Превышаем";
    break;
    case $speed < $limit:
        echo "Скорость в норме";
    break;
    case $speed == $limit:
        echo "Ты на грани";
    break;
    default:
        echo "Введи нормальную скорость";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Возможно вы опечатались? Я использовал следующий вариант, на основе вашего, работает. `switch(true){ case $speed > $limit: echo "Превышаем"; break; case $speed < $limit: echo "Скорость в норме"; break; default: echo "Ты на грани"; break; }`

Answer (score 3):

Если в кейсе стоит только одна команда, то классическое применение свитча в пхп (сравнение переменной с константой) обычно не имеет смысла, поскольку проще и удобнее выбрать значение из заранее определенного массива.

"Подобное" тому что написано в вопросе реализовывать на свитче не нужно. Получится больше писанины, чем с прстыми ифами.

Ну и если говорить о совсем конкретном случае, то он также также решается с помощью массива и [какой-то матери](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op).

```
$messages = [
    -1 => "Скорость в норме",
     0 =>  "Ты на грани",
     1 => "Превышаем",
    ];
echo $messages[$speed <=> $limit];
```

Comment: Стоит, однако, упомянуть что оператор какой-то ма...., космического корабля появился в php7.

Comment: Добавлю, корабли отлично летают и без переменной.

Answer (score 2):

Следующий код простой и подойдет для вашего изучения и уровня:

```
$speed = 90;
$limit = 80;

switch($speed) {
    case ($speed > $limit):
        echo "Не превышайте!";
        break;
    default: 
        echo "Все в норме :)";
}
```

Ключевое слово `default` обозначает "по умолчанию" - что если нет подходящих ветвлений `case` для `$speed`, то будет выполнено дествие "по умолчанию", описанное в `default`.

[switch-case конструкции](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)